# Unifying Optimal Control Problems through Constraint Optimization Problems.

Tags: optimization, optimal-control

Consider Optimization problem in the form 
$$\min ~ f(x) \quad \quad \text{subject to}\quad \quad F(x) \in C \subseteq  Y   $$

Where $F: X \to Y$ is continuously differentiable between banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ and $f$ is lipschitz function, and $C$ is closed convex set in $Y$. I'm wondering is there any class of optimal control problems fitted in above framework ?

I'm asking this, because KKT condition is available for above problem in literatures, and yet expert people in optimal control take different approach to ge necessary optimality condition! To my understanding an optimal control problem is just an Infinite dimensional optimization problem, why we can't employ one single approach to solve both.

My Guess:

I think the assumption $F$ be differentiable (in Frechet sense) is strong, and might make trouble to cover large class of optimal control problems.

Comment: Lots of optimal control problems fall into this framework. Can you elaborate what you mean by the different approach taken by folks in optimal control? Some variant of first order conditions are the basis of most common approaches in optimal control, so I am a little surprised by your assertion. Optimal control problems have aspects that are 'hidden' by the above formulation, so deeper analysis and results are available. For example, Potryagin's extreme principle doesn't apply a priori to the above formulation. Gateaux differentiablity or weaker forms of derivaitve are available.

Comment: @copper.hat  Do you know any reference where I can find some optimal control examples fitted in the above setting?  I just saw in the context of optimal control problems people never consider such generalty the specify their problem into their own format, like Boltza  problem.  It seems to me it is easier deal with general infinite dimension optimization problem and at the end specify the result in any specific case. I want $F$ be frechet differentiable.

Comment: LQR problems fit the framework. I guess I'm not sure what you mean by different approach, something akin to KKT is a precursor to deriving conditions that exploit the optimal control structure.

Comment: @copper.hat  In the problem you mentioned LQR, for $F$ being continuously differentiable, we need to have the mapping $x \to x^{\dot}$ be differentiable. It seems it is not even continuous under sum norm. How do you choose your $F$ and $C$ in LQR?