# Under what norm $F: X \to X'$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, optimal-control

Let $X = AC[0,1]$ be the space of all [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) functions from  $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $X'=\text{The space of all Lebesgue integrable functions}$.

Consider the linear function $F: X \to X'$ defined by $F(f)=f'$. In order to $F$ be well-defined we only consider $f'$ where it exists (It almost every where exists on $[0,1]$).  Clearly $F$ is linear, my question is that,  is there any interesting norm on $X$ or a subspace $Y \subset X$ with a suitable norm such that it turns $F$ a continuous function ?

I'm not looking for trivial norms. This operator frequently appear in optimal control, and the motivation of this question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281296/219176)

Comment: If $X=AC[0,1]$ then $F(f)=f'$ does not define a map from $X$ to $X$ in the first place. The derivative of an AC function can be any Lebesgue integrable function; it certainly need not be AC.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That's why I consider a room for considering a subspace of AC,  Like$ Y= C^{\infty} [0,1]$ .

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I will Edit the question, I only care the domain of $F$ be $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one dimension, you have $AC[0,1] = W^{1,1}(0,1)$, which is a Sobolev space. Moreover, your space $X'$ coincides with $L^1(0,1)$. Thus,

$$\| F(f) \|_{L^1} = \| f' \|_{L^1} \le \| f \|_{W^{1,1}}.$$
Therefore, $F$ is bounded with these natural norms.

Comment: Thanks !  By one dimension you mean $n =1$  ? does this also work for for any $n$ if consider the components of  $f$?

Comment: No, one dimension means $[0,1]\subset \mathbb R^1$.